# What assigned plan identifies OneDrive availability

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm using MS Graph API to process files available on OneDrive. Some tenant users don't have OneDrive enabled. I'm trying to detect such users based on provisioning plans.

I extract user data using [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) or [get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) requests. [User resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) has [an "assignedPlans" collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/assignedplan?view=graph-rest-1.0) that is supposed to describe plans assigned to each specific user. My question is what plans are supposed to include OneDrive or OneDrive for business?

I've researched a little bit and found following [assignedPlan->service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/assignedplan?view=graph-rest-1.0) values:

```
AADPremiumService
Adallom
AzureAdvancedThreatAnalytics
AzureAnalysis
Deskless
DynamicsHCMWorkload
DynamicsMarketing
DynamicsNAV
Exchange
Homeroom
KratosAppsService
MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline
MicrosoftFormsProTest
MicrosoftKaizala
MicrosoftOffice
MicrosoftStream
MSRemoteAssist
MultiFactorService
OfficeForms
PowerAppsService
PowerBI
ProcessSimple
SharePoint
Sway
TeamspaceAPI
To-Do
VolumeLicensing
Windows
WindowsDefenderATP
YammerEnterprise
```

Which of them suppose accesability of OneDrive/OD for business?

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive for Business availability is affected by several factors so there isn't a way using the assigned plans to make the determination.  The best way to determine whether a user has a OneDrive for Business is to look at the drive relationship of the user.

For example:
GET /user/{id}/drive

That will return null if the current user does not have a OneDrive for Business created.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, that's a very good idea! The only drawback I see is that it requires making additional Graph API call for each user. Of course I can perform a batch request, but as far as I know only 20 requests could be packed into a batch request. Maybe there is some hint in those plans, a hint that will allow me to lower the scope of users that require making additional Graph API calls. For example - if a user has a "SharePoint" plan enabled - it would definitely has a OneDrive available. Are there such hints?